# i3w missing/blank system dialogs

Tags: arch-linux, i3

When I open a system dialog (like File Open, Save As, etc.) in Firefox or Chromium I only get a white blank screen (no borders or anything).

As I can press escape/enter to dismiss the dialog I suspect that it is working but not visible.

I tried to toggle floating mode but the effect is always the same. How can I get the dialog to show?

Comment: Is there anything in your `i3` logs?

Comment: @pfnuesel thanks, after enabling the logs I finally found a solution :)

Comment: That was easy. For me at least. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks to @pfnuesel I found the answer in the i3 logs:

```
[..] window 0x014013e1 wants to be at -1670x-1466 with 6220x4644
```

and was able to fix it with:

```
floating_minimum_size 500 x 300
floating_maximum_size 2000 x 1500
for_window [class="(?i)firefox" instance="^(?!Navigator$)"] floating enable
```

Comment: This was most of the fix - is there a way to force it to keep the pop-ups onscreen?  Even with the above settings, mine was 3/4 offscreen and had to be dragged to where I could see it.

Comment: @pjz did you adjust the values to your screen resolution?

Comment: Yes, the size was correct, the _placement_ was just wrong initially.  Once dragged to a sane place the rest seem happy to follow suit.